# Hacked raid 5 on an enterprised system

Tags: raid, data-recovery

Here is my problem (big problem). I have a site that is using a Dell s310 with perc3. The raid is a 5 mirrored. It was hacked and used as a email server. Passwords were changed and now it will not even load the sign in screen. I need to get the data off and reload the server or it will be a 48 hour trip through hell.

I have tried using Active X to recover the data by slaving, but as you know raid can not be slaved and recognized as a drive. So here is my question can I setup a server Win2003 and put one of the drives in to get the data after I created a raid 5? Any other suggestions or fixes are more thank welcomed.

Comment: Hardware or Software RAID?

Answer (score 2):

When doing data recovery, the first you need is a bunch of at least semi-professional tools, and Windows doesn't have any on board. Best to get your hands on a Knoppix DVD or any Linux Live-CD distro that's specialized in data recovery tasks, and then get yourself started.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a PERC system, then you wont be able to import the drives with disk manager. You would do better looking for a DR company in your area.